# A password protected zip file is the encryption algorithm provided with iOS or Mac OS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, https, zip

I can not distinguish between "encryption algorithm provided in iOS or Mac OS (1)" and "industry standard algorithm not implemented in iOS (2)".

> case 2: The application uses or accesses the encryption algorithm provided in iOS or Mac OS and implements industry-standard algorithms not implemented in iOS as a security function
>
> -- US cryptographic registration (ERN) and approval of French import application are required

"HTTPS", "ATS", "Zip file with password"
Which of the above (1) or (2) is included in?

Also, in Case 2 above, is it necessary to approve the French import application even if only the U.K. App Store is open?

Answer (score -1):

The encryption method is specified in the 2 bytes with offset 8 of the file heather. See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) or [zip file format specification](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT)

Or rather read [this](https://courses.cs.ut.ee/MTAT.07.022/2015_fall/uploads/Main/dmitri-report-f15-16.pdf)